# second scrollview move animation glitch

Tags: ios, scrollview, uiviewanimation

For aesthetic/entertainment purposes to pan across a background image larger than the screen rather than push a second view, I'm trying to combine the functions of two views, one that was the root view, the second that was a push view onto it.

So, the root view has a button that when tapped, initiates the panning of the scroll view to the right rather than pushing a second view. This works just fine:

```
- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender {
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    _scrollViewToPan.contentOffset = CGPointMake(645, 0.0);
}];
```

}

What appears now appears on the screen that was the second view involves the user inputting some information. All this worked as a second push view before I tried to combine it into the one view. Now that they are combined, there is a glitch in the scroll view animation when it moves to accommodate the keyboard in the keyboardWasShown:(see below) - it jumps to the original coordinates before scrolling into place above the keyboard.

```
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(645, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
_scrollViewToPan.contentInset = contentInsets;
_scrollViewToPan.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (activeField == _nameTextView){
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake (645, 160);
    [_scrollViewToPan setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}

if (activeField == _addressTextView){
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake (645, 160);
    [_scrollViewToPan setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

keyboardWillBeHidden:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    _scrollViewToPan.contentOffset = CGPointMake(645, 0.0);
}];
```

When this was a separate view, scrollPoint was (0,160) and all worked well. I changed it to (645, 160) to align with the first offset from panning described above. However, when the user taps on the textView, rather than scrolling smoothly up in conjunction with the keyboard appearance, it jumps to the original pre-panned coordinate then scrolls right and up such that it does finally end in the correct place.

In a nutshell, what I want is original coordinate A --> (tap button) --> scrolls to coordinate B --> tap textView/keyboard shows --> scrolls to coordinate C --> keyboard dismissed --> scrolls to coordinate B.

What I get is original coordinate A --> (tap button) --> scrolls to coordinate B --> tap textView/keyboard shows --> (jumps to A then scrolls to C) --> keyboard dismissed --> scrolls to coordinate B.

How can I get rid of the 'jump-to-A' glitch?

Comment: By jumping to A, then scrolling to C, does that mean that the transition from A to C means that it's scrolling diagonally?

Comment: I figure there might be a side effect from something in your code that's modifying the scrollview. I would try to debug this by making a conditional breakpoint on `-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:]`, then turning it on right before you tap the text view and figuring out what part of your code is causing it by running up the stack.

Comment: Problem seems to be inherent in the definition of setContentOffset:setContentOffset:animated:
Sets the offset from the content view’s origin that corresponds to the receiver’s origin.  So it's restarting from the origin as advertised. And yet it doesn't do that when the keyboard disappears, which seems to be inconsistent behavior. Unfortunately I'm not savvy to the mysterious ways of breakpoints and stack running... yet.

Comment: It only jumps the first time the textView is selected. If reselected, it properly scrolls only upward to accommodate the keyboard without the jump-back-to-the-origin glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation wires were crossing somewhere in the addition of contentInsets into the mix. Instead of adding this on the fly for the keyboard, I made my scrollView bigger in its IB settings so the keyboard height is already accounted for. Then simplified keyboardWasShown to:

```
    if (activeField == _nameTextView){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        _scrollViewToPan.contentOffset = CGPointMake(645, 140);
    }];
}
if (activeField == _addressTextView){

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        _scrollViewToPan.contentOffset = CGPointMake(645, 205);
    }];
```

Animates properly with vertical-only scroll to accommodate keyboard upon first and subsequent selection by user.